# Angular - Get element's click binding expression

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-directive

Given the following markup:

```html
<button class="btn" (click)="chain()" promiseDirective></button>
```

And assuming my `chain()` method returns a promise, I would like to obtain the expression value of the `click` binding so I can then access it in my directive:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[promiseDirective]'
})
export class PlPromisesDirective implements OnInit {
  @Input() promiseDirective: any;
  @Input() click: any; // Maybe get the value through here

  private subject: Subject<any>;
  private subscription: Subscription;

  constructor() {
    this.subject = new Subject<any>();
  }

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.subscription = this.subject
      .asObservable()
      .pipe(map(value => Promise.resolve<any>(value)))
      .subscribe(value => this.promiseHandler(value, this.$element));
  }

  @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
  public clickEventHandler(event: MouseEvent) {
    // And maybe access it here
    console.log(value);
  }
}
```

I have tried to bind the `click` property but the value always come as `undefined`.

---

### **Edit**

While @selem mn answer is satisfatory, I would like to avoid the need for a second binding to detect a change has been made to the value as this is already possible by the `@Input() plPromise` binding.

What I really needed was a way to listen directly to the `(click)` expression result so I could make the directive usage way more practical.

Answer (score 0):

### First way

I think, if you depend on that value in your directive, then should implement the method there:

```
@Directive({
  selector: 'button[promiseDirective]'
})
 // ....
 @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
  public clickEventHandler(event: MouseEvent) {
    // Call your service here
  }
```

And remove that `(click)` from your button tag since your directive will handle click events by itself by `@HostListener` :

```
<button class="btn" promiseDirective></button>
```

---

### Second way:

Or you can add another `@Input` without changing the core of your method there, means:

```
@Directive({
  selector: 'button[promiseDirective]'
})

@Input() valueOfPromise;
 // ....
 ngOnChanges() // <-- would be invoked once @Input() value is updated
    console.log(this.valueOfPromise);    
  }
```

Do not forget to import and implement `OnChanges` interface in your directive class, then your button snippet should be like:

```
<button [valueOfPromise]="returnedValue" (click)="chain()" class="btn" promiseDirective></button>
```

And for the relevant TS part of the button:

```
public returnedValue;

chain() {
 // Call your service
   this.returnedValue = data // <-- data is your returned data from service
}
```

Here you wont need anymore `@HostListener`.

Comment: Yes I could do something like that, however, I am currently working on upgrading an AngularJS application to Angular and this directive I used all over the place. That makes it impratical to change the core behaviour of the directive

Comment: @EpaXapate, in angularJS there was a similar directive that can get your returned values as you'd described above ?

Comment: Sort of, in AngularJS I could get the attribute raw value and use the ``$parse`` service to get the expression value, thus giving me the hability to override the ``click`` event and do whatever I needed to do

Comment: The second way you described is already implemented in the directive, please check my updated question for further details.

Comment: @EpaXapate if you already have your value in `@Input() plPromise: any;` (although am not seeing that input reference in your button HTML tag), i do not really get the point why would u proceed more. Anyway, AFAIK, there is no such builtin way to do that in angular. And frankly, i do not get why u added a second input and a hostlistener decorator just to get a value that it is already there in ur first input.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184157/discussion-between-epaxapate-and-selem-mn).